# Firebase DataStructure

Tags: real-time, firebase

I am trying to create a "Users" list. But I am not able to replicate the way it is structured in the docs https://www.firebase.com/images/data_structure.png.

Instead my structure has a Users with child nodes having some raw text. https://www.evernote.com/shard/s52/sh/21c878d6-4978-440c-a089-10da4fb6d792/2d0d7a90861ef6f94e425fdb904b8ab2 Instead I want child nodes named as 'john','terry' etc as shown in your docs.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Could you give more detail? Firebase data can be structured any way you like.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of my datastructure. Hope it explains you. Thanks @AndrewLee

Comment: Got it! Thanks for sending the screenshot. Sounds like you should be using "child" instead of "push". See Kato's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're talking about the keys. In the Firebase example, the keys are things like `fred`, but in your data they appear as `-iKvpJ...`

If you insert your records using `push`, then Firebase automatically assigns the key:

```
firebase.child('users').push({ name: 'Fred' });

// /users/-KvpJ.../name/Fred
```

Use `child` and `set` to specify your own keys:

```
firebase.child('users/fred').set({ name: 'Fred' });

// /users/fred/name/Fred
```